# is it expected that data terraform_remote_sate creates state when it does not exist?

Tags: terraform

I'm defining a remote state data resource (gcp backend) in terraform. When I plan, the state file, for the remote state, is created if it does not exist previously, even when I'm not referencing the state in other resources.

Terraform v0.11.14

So when I plan for env `dev`:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "example" {
  backend   = "gcs"
  workspace = "dev-us-east1"

  config {
    bucket = "bucket"
    prefix = "global/projects/example-project"
  }
}
```

and the file in gcs `bucket/global/projects/example-project/dev-us-east1` does not exist, then it's created as an empty state.

I expected kind of a `state not found` error, but instead, the remote state is created with an empty content.